# Django ERROR "Intersection is not supported on this database backend"

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I just convert database backend from sqlite to mysql.
But When I test my feature in project is ERROR.

```
NotSupportedError at /filter/
intersection is not supported on this database backend.
```

In my view.py have Django ORM Union, Intersection. I think this is the troublemakers. Why It can't use Union, Intersection in MySql Backend.
I try to fix it. But I don't know how. Please Help me T^T

Answer (score 1):

Because the MySQL backend does not support intersection. From Django source:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/a906c9898284a9aecb5f48bdc534e9c1273864a6/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py

```
supports_select_intersection = False
```

You can switch to another database backend which supports intersection, or rewrite your query in a way that doesn't require intersections.